# How to integrate OpenCV.js in a React WebApp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opencv

I'm new to Javascript and React. I would like to embed OpenCV.js into a basic React.js web app to build an online client-side document scanner (I already have the image processing pipeline developped in Python).

I used `yarn create react-app` to get a basic working React sandbox containing : `App.js` which is the main React component and `index.js` which plugs it into the DOM. I added a custom `imageProcessing.js` file that will contain my image processing pipeline. A `yarn start` command is available to compile everything and display the result in my browser.

In order to use OpenCV in this pipeline, I downloaded `opencv.js` from [official page](https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js), put it next to `imageProcessing.js` and finally called it through `const cv = require('../lib/opencv')`.
The problem is the `yarn start` command compiles sources for hours and it is clearly not possible to develop anything.

Now my question is : how to efficiently compile my web app with that heavy `opencv.js` (13MB) in my sources ? 
Is their a better way of integrating the lib ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Include `opencv.js` as `<script>` in your index.html instead.

Comment: you can check also https://brainhub.eu/blog/opencv-react-native-image-processing/

Comment: Thanks, Chris G. I'm really sorry for my huge misunderstanding of these language but now i have a ` <script async src="../src/lib/opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my HTML file, how should i import it in my `imageProcessing.js`  in order to use for instance `cv.imread()` in it ?

Comment: If `imageProcessing.js` gets bundled by webpack, you need to put `/* global cv */` at the top. This *should* allow you to use `cv` in your scripts without lint complaining about cv being undefined.

Comment: @fewber did you find solution can you post your code?

Comment: Hi @thug_. The compilation was endless so I decided to use alternative image processing primitives to achieve my goal.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer @fweber. I am running into similar issues, so trying to look into alternatives.

Comment: @thug_ I am faaar from being a pro in JS and I certainly understand less than half of what is going on during compilation. You may be luckier than me at finding an `openCV` solution

Comment: Hi I'm facing the same issue. OpenCV.JS is doable or not, or we should use iOS, Android native module for openCV C/Java? Hope the discussion continue although the poster decided to go another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cdn instead of using locally this way react won't bother you. (but make sure that you don't have/have sufficient data limit because opencv.js is a heavy library & it'll request everytime when you reload page...) but you can store that library in catch with PWA so that it'll store opencv.js in browser's cache & whenever you reload page it'll send cached file instead of request 1000s of times... & obviously it'll reduce bandwidth usage & other point is you can use their functions methods in useEffect or outside component function

```
// opencv.js code here

function App(props){...}
```

OR

```
function App(props){
    useEffect(() => {

    // opencv.js code here

    }, [])
}
```

make sure to let the user know that some heavy loading in background running while loading the opencv.js file...