# Failed to compile opencv.js with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opencv, npm

Made a react web app with `create-react-app` and added the `opencv.js` file to use it in my app.

When I start the app with `npm start' it says:

```
Failed to compile

./src/lib/opencv.js
  Line 2:39:        'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 4:5:         'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 30:2024:     'read' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 30:2180:     'readbuffer' is not defined                                            no-undef
  Line 30:2200:     'read' is not defined                                                  no-undef
```

And the list goes on.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you plz elaborate... also share opencv.js content if possible..

Comment: Check this once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517131/how-to-integrate-opencv-js-in-a-react-webapp

Comment: @SariqShaikh I read it but it doesn't help.

Comment: @gdh I used this `opencv.js`: https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js
I have this file in the /lib folder, and use it with `const cv = require('/path/to/opencv.js'')`